# How to get the (new) Azure PHP SDK to work?

Tags: php, azure, composer-php, azure-table-storage

I've got the old PHP azure SDK working on a Azure website, but I would like to migrate to the new one. Unfortunately, I'm unable to get the new one to work.

I've installed the SDK manually and followed the "Usage" steps on this page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php. Instead of 'use' I use 'require', maybe that's where it goes wrong but I don't know how to use namespaces.

The environment I use to edit my code is dreamweaver.

The following code goes wrong at the line starting with `$tableRestProxy`

```
<?php
    require("WindowsAzure/WindowsAzure.php"); 
    require("WindowsAzure/Common/ServicesBuilder.php");
    require("WindowsAzure/Common/ServiceException.php");
    require("WindowsAzure/Table/TableRestProxy.php");       

    $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[AccountName];AccountKey=[AccountKey]';
    // I do know that I have to declare the AccountName and AccountKey here. Left it out for privacy reasons.       

    $tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($connectionString);
?>
```

---

**update**

Now I'm trying to use Composer to install the SDK. My composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "microsoft/windowsazure": "*"
    },          
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

When I run the composer.phar I get the following result:

```
Onwijs@JEROENVINK /e/Users/Public/Documents/00_speeltuin_azure/newsdk
$ php composer.phar diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: FAIL

The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
Disabling it when using Composer is recommended, but should not cause issues bey
ond slowness.
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK

Onwijs@JEROENVINK /e/Users/Public/Documents/00_speeltuin_azure/newsdk
$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.php.net
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for microsoft/windowsazure 0.4.0 -> satisfiable by mi
crosoft/windowsazure[v0.4.0].
    - microsoft/windowsazure v0.4.0 requires pear-pear/http_request2 * -> no mat
ching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common
 problems.
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How have you installed the SDK? using Composer or Pear?

Comment: @SyntaxC4 No, I installed it manually; http://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/php-download-sdk/. But I see now that the SDK has dependencies on other packages, I'll try that now.

Comment: @SyntaxC4 Now I'm trying to install via Composer but I get the following result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z54ezpki1136bpx/Screenshot%202014-06-26%2011.17.34.png This is the first time I'm using Composer, do you see what I'm doing wrong? This is my composer.json file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/klebxcycpaay7w4/Screenshot%202014-06-26%2011.20.04.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with pear and the Azure SDK via composer.

I found a way around it by modifying my composer.json file to look something like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "microsoft/windowsazure": "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/http_request2": "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mime": "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mimedecode": "*"
    },          
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Notice the three lines:

```
"pear-pear.php.net/http_request2": "*",
"pear-pear.php.net/mail_mime": "*",
"pear-pear.php.net/mail_mimedecode": "*"
```

these provide more explicit information to composer and using this approach things seem to compose just fine.

Hope that helps.